# Uncaught referenceerror: 'functionName' is not defined on api 22

Tags: javascript, android, referenceerror

We are just updating our app to support Lollipop 5.0.x and 5.1.x and have run ourselves into a wall trying to figure out what to do. The app runs fine in Kitkat builds and the call to `fetchAllData()` from `finalValidate()` works like a charm. However, the same build when run on a device/emulator throws the uncaught reference error : fetchAllData is not defined. The code works as follows :

```
finalValidate = function(){

//check if all fields are filled
// check if network is available
fetchAllData();
}
```

`fetchAllData()` is defined in another JS page. And both have been included in the main `index.html`.

Browsing on net tells me, that `fetchAllData()` is not accessible from `finalValidate()` but then, if that is the case, the build shouldn't even be running on Kitkat devices.

Comment: Not so many details here, so first dumb question in mind: did you include the js containing fetchAllData, before the one with finalValidate? :)
And from the comment I read: "check if network is available" What are you using to do the check? Are you sure that the problem is fetchAllData and not inside it?

Comment: I did check the include hierarchy before posting this question and yes, the js with fetchAllData is included before the one with finalValidate. Interestingly enough, upon trying, the build works in kitkat device even when the js are not included in their proper order.

Comment: We are using the cordova Connection api Object with connection.type property to check for available network. The control does not even reach fetchAllData() as confirmed with console.logs and alerts inside the function.

Comment: If you change the script tag order, everything works on Kitkat? This is strange, a script tag with a src attribute is loaded synchronously. So order matter! Have you tried to completely uninstall the application and install it again?

Comment: Finally found the root of the issue. It had actually nothing to do with the file reference. The json that was getting fetched from fetchAllData() had some unwanted extra characters which were not being identified during the call. Removing those extra characters helped fix that issue.